# Python3 pathlib one-liner for checking if Path has at least one file of a certain extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

My first try yielded this result:

```
if [p for p in Path().glob('*.ext')]:
```

Which I guess is inefficient since the entirety of the generator object (which `.glob()` returns) has to be consumed by the list comprehension before proceeding.

My second try was to manually call `.__next__()` on the generator and catch `StopIteration` manually, but I don't believe that can be done in one line:

```py
try:
    Path().glob('*.ext').__next__()
except StopIteration:
    # no ".ext" files exist here
else:
    # at least one ".ext" file exists here
```

I'm a Python noob in general and I'm wondering if a one-liner solution is possible (at least one that's more efficient than my first attempt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(p for p in Path().glob('*.ext')):
   # ...
```

or even more simply,

```
if any(Path().glob('*.ext')):
   # ...
```